# Multidimensional array as JSON response

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Aim is to return array from .php in JSON format. That array to contain another array of data (49 DB rows, each having 4 columns), which is taken form mySQL DB:

.php is below:

```
$json = array( //this is AJAX response
        "status" => null, 
        "username" => null,
        "population" => null,
        "food" => null,
        "water" => null,
        "map" => null //this to be an array of tiles
    );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM players_map_test WHERE player_id = :value";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $json["map"]["tile_health"] = $row["tile_health"];
        $json["map"]["tile_id"] = $row["tile_id"];
        $json["map"]["tile_level"] = $row["tile_level"];
        $json["map"]["tile_type"] = $row["tile_type"];
    }
echo json_encode($json);
```

In my AJAX response handler, I expect to access that sub-array as response.map and handle elements in usual manner: response.map[0].

When I console.log(response) I see that map is present there, but it is not an array and it contains "1" as values to all keys:

```
map:Object
    tile_health:"1"
    tile_id:"1"
    tile_level:"1"
    tile_type:"1"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$json["map"]["tile_health"]  = $row["tile_health"];`: You are overwriting your values in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Update your **foreach** loop like as below--

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $json["map"][] = $row;
}
```

Also change the below code

```
#$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

*Note:* **fetch()** function return only 1 row. And **fetchAll()** function return multiple rows.

Comment: This one seems to produce some result, but unfortunately I am having only 1 row of data instead of 49 rows. Id of that row is 49 though... I seems to be overwriting something again?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check my answer. @Vadimster

Comment: Or you can direct assign $json["map"][] = $result; After using fetchAll() @Vadimster

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is next:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $json["map"][] = [
        "tile_health" => $row["tile_health"],
        "tile_id" => $row["tile_id"],
        "tile_level" => $row["tile_level"],
        "tile_type" => $row["tile_type"]
    ];
}
```

You were overwriting values.

Comment: Unfortunately getting an error "unexpected '['". If I change into array(...); the outcome is strange: all keys have same values.

Comment: Did you try to use fetchAll instead of fetch?

Comment: I am actually looking into this or alternatively putting the fetch() statement into while loop! I hope it works. I missed that fetch() returns only one result.

Comment: This code worked with me: `foreach ($result as $row) {
  $json["map"][] = array(
   "tile_health" => $row["tile_health"],
         "tile_id" => $row["tile_id"],
         "tile_level" => $row["tile_level"],
         "tile_type" => $row["tile_type"]
   );    
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your database part like this:

```
// request only needed columns
$sql = "SELECT tile_health, tile_id, tile_level, tile_type 
        FROM players_map_test WHERE player_id = :value";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// output was already in the type of array
$json["map"] = $result;

// encode and display
echo json_encode($json);
```